# merge each record if IDs is same using hash of array

Tags: perl

I have two files, (1) Uniq_ID.txt having IDs, (2) Information.txt having ID and corresponding information. Each ID may have one or more corresponding information in File (2). I want to print information in single line separated by ";" if ID matches between two files.

(1) Uniq_ID.txt

```
a12
b13
c14
d15
```

(2) Information.txt

```
a12 AAA BBB
a12 ppp yyy
b13 CCC DDD
b13 GGG SSS
c14 HHH KKK
c14 JJJ OOO
d15 LLL LLL
```

Expected Output

```
a12:a12 AAA BBB;a12 ppp yyy
b13:b13 CCC DDD;b13 GGG SSS
c14:c14 HHH KKK;c14 JJJ OOO
d15:d15 LLL LLL
```

program.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                          
#./program.pl Uniq_ID.txt Information.txt                                                                        
@aa=();
%data=();
@arrayname=();
$file1=$ARGV[0];
$file2=$ARGV[1];
open(FP1, $file1);
while($name1=<FP1>)
{
  chomp($name1);
  #collect the name according to the Uniq_ID                                                           
  $arrayname[$i]=$name1;
  $i++;
  open(FP2, $file2);
  while($info=<FP2>)
  {
    chomp($info);
    @aa=split(/\s/,$info);
    $name2=$aa[0];
    $seq=$aa[1];
    #if name in Uniq_ID is same with name in information.txt                                                    
    if($name1 =~ /^$name2$/)
    {                                                          
        #hash of arrays"                                                                          
        #put each line of information.txt into a Uniq_ID                                                     
        push @{$data{$arrayname[$i]}}, $info;
      }
  }
}
foreach (@arrayname){
print "$_:\t@{$data{$_}}\n";
}
```

I run the program using "./program.pl Uniq_ID.txt Information.txt" but getting the following result

```
a12:
b13:
c14:
d15:
```

Could you kindly tell me what was wrong in my program. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you increment `$i` after putting `$name1` into `$arrayname` at that index, then try to access the element again at `$i`, which is now one past it. Increment `$i` after storing `$info`, or use `push` instead.

```
while($name1=<FP1>)
{
  chomp($name1);
  #collect the name according to the Uniq_ID                                                           
  $arrayname[$i]=$name1; # <-- You insert into the array at $i here 
  $i++;                  # <-- You increment $i here
  open(FP2, $file2);
  while($info=<FP2>)
  {
    chomp($info);
    @aa=split(/\s/,$info);
    $name2=$aa[0];
    $seq=$aa[1];
    #if name in Uniq_ID is same with name in information.txt                                                    
    if($name1 =~ /^$name2$/)
    {                                                          
        #hash of arrays"                                                                          
        #put each line of information.txt into a Uniq_ID                                                     
        push @{$data{$arrayname[$i]}}, $info; # <-- You access the element at $i here
      }
  }
  # <-- You should increment $i here (but use push instead)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All that is necessary is to `push` each line onto the appropriate element of the hash. It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @ids;

open my $fh, '<', 'Uniq_ID.txt';
push @ids, (split)[0] while <$fh>;

my %data;

open $fh, '<', 'Information.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id) = split;
  push @{ $data{$id} }, $_;
}

for my $id (@ids) {
  printf "%s:%s\n", $id, join ';', @{ $data{$id} };
}
```

**output**

```
a12:a12 AAA BBB;a12 ppp yyy
b13:b13 CCC DDD;b13 GGG SSS
c14:c14 HHH KKK;c14 JJJ OOO
d15:d15 LLL LLL
```

Answer (score 2):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.  Also include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) if you do any file processing.

Your code can be simplified a lot by processing each file just once, like demonstrated below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($id_file, $info_file) = @ARGV;

my %info;
open my $fh, '<', $info_file; # \"a12 AAA BBB\na12 ppp yyy\nb13 CCC DDD\nb13 GGG SSS\nc14 HHH KKK\nc14 JJJ OOO\nd15 LLL LLL";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id) = split;
    push @{$info{$id}}, $_;
}

open $fh, '<', $id_file; # \"a12\nb13\nc14\nd15";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_:" . join(';', @{$info{$_}}) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a12:a12 AAA BBB;a12 ppp yyy
b13:b13 CCC DDD;b13 GGG SSS
c14:c14 HHH KKK;c14 JJJ OOO
d15:d15 LLL LLL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using `perl` that can be ran from the command line:

```
perl -lne '
BEGIN {
    $x = pop; 
    push @{$h{$_->[0]}}, "@$_" for map [split], <>; 
    @ARGV = $x
}
print "$_:" . join ";" , @{ $h{$_} }' Information.txt Uniq_ID.txt
```

#### Output:

```
a12:a12 AAA BBB;a12 ppp yyy
b13:b13 CCC DDD;b13 GGG SSS
c14:c14 HHH KKK;c14 JJJ OOO
d15:d15 LLL LLL
```